# Scrape Table With JavaScript "Show More Button" In Webpage

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to pull a data table from a NYT open-access web article on the number of COVID-19 cases, which can be found [here](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/coronavirus-us-cases.html). The table shows the top 10 states with highest number of cases, and expands to all 50 states and U.S. territories upon clicking the "Show more" button.

[image]

The HTML portion of the table is as follows:

[image]

Using [this](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-dynamic-page-2f8ad15efe25) tutorial, I have written the following code utilizing Selenium to try clicking this button, and pass this page off to BeautifulSoup to begin synthesizing for use in Pandas. My initial code looks as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/coronavirus-us-cases.html")
```

At this juncture, I am not sure how to execute clicking the button (found in the HTML snippet: `<button class="svelte-1tjczrs">Show more</button>`), and stage it for BeautifulSoup.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following attempt. It should fetch you the required content unveiling show more button and put the same in a dataframe.

```
import pandas
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/coronavirus-us-cases.html"

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get(link)

    datalist = []

    show_more = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#g-cases-by-state button[class^='svelte']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",show_more)

    for elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#g-cases-by-state table[class^='svelte'] tr"))):
        data = [item.text for item in elem.find_elements_by_css_selector("th,td")]
        datalist.append(data)

df = pandas.DataFrame(datalist)
print(df)
```

Comment: This works perfectly @SIM, your help is greatly appreciated! I was missing some key steps that some of the other articles lacked/glossed over. I'll be accepting this answer!

Comment: This error does get thrown when running in a script, any ideas on how to avoid? selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="svelte-1tjczrs">...</button> is not clickable at point (513, 567). Other element would receive the click: <a class="dockCard__content" href="https://www.nytimes.com/news-event/coronavirus" target="_blank">...</a>
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

Comment: I've modified the selectors within the script which change very frequently in that site. This time the selector will last long unless there is a major change. Thanks.

Comment: You read my mind, I noticed the HTML string changes roughly once every 24 hours. Your answers have been very thorough, I greatly appreciate your responsiveness!